# Leaflet AngularFire2 code in button 1st click works 1 time 2nd click works 2 time 3nd click works 3 time

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, leaflet, angularfire

```
    CollectPixi(){

         this.map.locate({setView:true,maxzoom:30}).on("locationfound",e=>{
           this.db.list(`/pixidata`).snapshotChanges().map(actions=>{
             return actions.map(action => {
                     const $key = action.payload.key;
                     const data = { $key, ...action.payload.val() };
                     return data;
                 });
             }).subscribe(items => {

               let pixizaa = items.map(this.getObjectWithoutKnowingKey);

               console.log(pixizaa);
               });




              });
}
```

CollectPixi function is in button.

When i click button 1 time i get console.log(pixizaa) output 1 time.
if i click it second time i get output 2 times
if i click 3rd time i get output 3 times.

html:

```
  <button ion-button class="button-collectpixi" (click)="CollectPixi()"  block>Collect Pixi!</button>
```

I clicked button 3 times. why its not 3 
[image]

acording to the answer

```
this.map.locate({setView:true,maxzoom:30}).on("locationfound",e=>{

}
```

is the reason of repetition.but i need to use e.latitude e.longitude values inside collectpixi function.i mean i take user location data and do some calculations with it inside collectpixi data.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the `onlocationfound` event handler **once**:

```
this.map.on("locationfound",e=>{
  ...
});
```

And run `locate` every time you press the button:

```
function CollectPixi() {
    this.map.locate({setView:true,maxzoom:30});
}
```

Do **not** call `map.on('locationfound', ...)` every time you click a button.

Comment: i need users location data inside function.how to do that then.because i take location with e.lattitude e.longitude